# nested dictionary generation based on values from other dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two input datasets one is list (list1) containing list of dictionaries with keys and count values,

```
list1 = [{u'key': u'1', u'count': 2}, {u'key': u'2', u'count': 1}, {u'key': u'3', u'count': 5}]
```

and other one is dictionary (dict1) with numbers(string) as key and status string as values.

```
dict1 = {'1': "status1", '2': "status2", '3': "status3"}
```

I need to generate a dictionary something like this {"status_string": {"count": "", "percent": ""}} where count is calculated based on value of the key from corresponding dict in list1. for example for key == 1 we get count == 2. And percent is calculated based on previous status count values starting from total_count, see the desired output below for percent.

## Desired output

```
result = {
"status1": {
    "count": {
        "value_from_list1_where_key = 1"
    },
    "percent": {
        "(last_calculated_count / total_count)"
    }
},
"status2": {
    "count": {
        "value_from_list1_where_key = 2"
    },
    "percent": {
        "(last_calculated_count/status1_count)"
    }
},
"status3": {
    "count": {
        "value_from_a_list_where_key = 3"
    },
    "percent": {
        "(last_calculated_count/status2_count)"
    }
}
```

}

## Example for above sample:

```
list1 = [{u'key': u'1', u'count': 2}, {u'key': u'2', u'count': 1}, {u'key': u'3', u'count': 5}]

dict1 = {'1': "status1", '2': "status2", '3': "status3"}

total_count = 10 #any integer value

result = {"status1": {"count": 2, "percent": 2/10}, 
      "status2": {"count": 1, "percent": 1/2},
      "status3": {"count": 5, "percent": 5/1}}
```

I am able to get the desired response by normal looping over the list of dictionaries and then putting if/else conditions to check and generate result, but i won't find it very pythonic. Could anyone please suggest what is the best/pythonic way to achieve same?

Comment: list1 is not very pythonic.  It's basically a list of key:value pairs (which you would think should go in a dict).  Do you want a pythonic way to redesign the data structures, or a pythonic way to iterate them AS-IS?

Comment: Hi Kenny thanks for the comment....actually the list1 is the result of one of the aggregation query on elastic search, so i am just reading it. BTW we can modify to suit the requirement...:)

Answer (score 1):

This should work, by converting list1 to a proper dictionary, and sorting dict1 into a list. (Hence you had it the opposite of the way it should have been to begin with). It then creates a generator that can be used to yield a dictionary.

This also assumes that every key in dict1 is also found in list1. Note that you will get `ZeroDivisionError` if any of the counts are zero (except for the last one, but you are just lucky then). I don’t know what you want as the expected result if that happened so you will need to elaborate.

```
from __future__ import division # without this you will get 0 for most of your percents

L = [{u'key': u'1', u'count': 2}, {u'key': u'2', u'count': 1}, {u'key': u'3', u'count': 5}]
D = {'1': "status1", '2': "status2", '3': "status3"}

def gen_result(list1, dict1, total_count):
    counts = {k['key']: k['count'] for k in list1} # makes list1 accessible by key value
    statuses = sorted(dict1.items()) # sorts the statuses in ascending order
    for key, status in statuses:
        count = counts[key] # accesses the count value from list1 (via counts dict)
        yield status, {'count': count, 'percent': count/total_count} # yields a key, value pair for the dictionary result
        total_count = count # sets total_count equal to the current count value, so that it can be compared to the next count value on the next iteration.

print(dict(gen_result(L, D, 10))) # materializes dictionary

#>>> {'status1': {'count': 2, 'percent': 0.2}, 
#     'status3': {'count': 5, 'percent': 5.0}, 
#     'status2': {'count': 1, 'percent': 0.5}}
```

Comment: I think you're supposed to get total_count by sum

Comment: question author wants it by comparison to the previous count, not by sum. See the expected result given in the question. “percent” is probably just bad terminology on their part. I believe the total_count value is arbitrary, as it’s commented as "any integer value" and the counts in the list add up to 8, not 10.

Comment: re-reading, I have no idea what percent is supposed to be. Nevermind. :)

Comment: I wonder if it should be sorted by key (as you have done), or use the ordering of the list, which happens to be in the same order, possibly by accident.

Comment: @KennyOstrom that is a good point and we will need the OP to clarify that. The fact that the keys are strings and not ints makes it even less clear whether or not they’re supposed to convey ordering.

Comment: @KennyOstrom ...please don't get confused with percent ...we are actually calculating the percent there but for the sake for making less complex with all that calculation terms, i just put the division part there as we need to calculate that based on pervious counts. Ignore the name there please.

Answer (score 0):

```
from operator import itemgetter as get

def convert(key_counts, key_to_status, total):
    counts = map(get('count'), key_counts)
    keys = map(get('key'), key_counts)
    status_counts = zip(map(key_to_status.get, keys), counts)
    totals = [total] + counts[:-1]
    return { status: {'count': count, 'percent': count/total}
                for (status, count), total in zip(status_counts, totals) }

if __name__ == '__main__':
    list1 = [{u'key': u'1', u'count': 2}, {u'key': u'2', u'count': 1}, {u'key': u'3', u'count': 5}] 

    dict1 = {'1': "status1", '2': "status2", '3': "status3"}

    total_count = 10 #any integer value 

    print(convert(list1, dict1, total_count))

# returns {'status1': {'count': 2, 'percent': 0},
#          'status3': {'count': 5, 'percent': 5},
#          'status2': {'count': 1, 'percent': 0}}
```

If you want float division, you have to replace `count/total` with `float(count)/total`.